# Form submit to Textarea on submit

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am attempting to create a form that outputs the entered data when "submit" is clicked to a textarea.

Currently I can get it to submit to the area below the form but am unsure how to have multiple ID's in a single textarea.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_input").value;
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_name").value;
        document.getElementById('stepsTaken').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_stepsTaken").value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
        document.getElementById('theDate').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_theDate").value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javaScript">
 function Qreplace(e) {
    var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
    var regex = /#test/gi;
    textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "1. test\n2. test");
    var regex = /#report/gi;
    textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "1. report\n2. report");
    }
 </script>

 <form action="javascript:void(0);">
<p>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label><p>
    <input type="text" id="user_input" required><p>
    <label><b>Enter a name</b></label><p>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" required><p>
    <textarea id="user_stepsTaken" onkeyup="Qreplace('user_stepsTaken')" placeholder="Actions taken and notes..." style="height: 91px; max-height: 350px;" required></textarea>
          <label for="sme">TL/SME Assist*</label>

        <br>
    
    Yes <input required="" type="radio" onclick="javascript:smeCheck();" value="Yes" name="TL/SME" id="yesCheck"> 
    No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:smeCheck();" value="No" name="TL/SME" id="noCheck"><br>
    <div id="ifyes" style="display:none">

        <input type="text" id="smeAssist" name="smeAssist" placeholder="Name or Initials of the TL/SME that provided assistance">
            <!-- Hide/Show SME additonal options based on radio check box -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function smeCheck() {
                  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
                    document.getElementById('ifyes').style.display = 'block';
                  } else document.getElementById('ifyes').style.display = 'none';
              
                } 
            </script>
    </div>
    <div style="display:block; margin-left: 0px;">
      <label for="dateStarted">Issue Started*</label>
      <input type="date" id="user_theDate" name="theDate" class="select">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
 </form>


 <label>Your input: </label>
 <p><span id='display'></span></p>
 <p><span id='name'></span></p>
 <div id='stepsTaken'></div>
 <div id='theDate'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help I am quite unfamiliar with Javascript.

So the end result I am trying to accomplish is have the user input to output into a textarea with the following formatting below.

---

Message: Message here

Name: Name here

Info: Actions Taken

Date: 2018-12-13

Comment: *but am unsure how to have multiple ID's in a single textarea* huh?

Comment: Maybe you could make a minimal example of the part you don't understand.

Comment: Concate all the values in JavaScript then print it to your desired textarea by ID

Comment: Your question is unclear.. this is first.. @connexo has a point.. this is second.. Can you please explain the above with the minimal verifiable question possible?

Comment: Apologies I was unsure how to best explain, What I am trying to do is have the values entered into the inputs in question output into a text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue using Jquery as follows

```js
$('#summary').click(function() {
  var name = $('#clientName').val()
  var message = $('#errorMessage').val()
  
  var ret = "Name: "+name+" \n\rMessage: " + message;
  console.log(ret)
  
  $(".output-container").fadeIn();
  $("#output").text(ret);
})

$("#copyForm").click(function(){
    $("#output").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $(".success").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
body {font-family: Helvetica;background-color: #1E365E;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #1E365E;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button] {
    background-color: #1E365E;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio] {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=date] {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #1E365E;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color: #1E365E;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5%;
}

.output-container {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#output {
  height: 300px;
}

.success {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h2>Testing Copy</h2>

  <form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="cName">Client Name*</label>
    <input type="text" id="clientName" name="cName" placeholder="Client Name...">

    <label for="errorMessage">Error Message</label>
    <input type="text" id="errorMessage" name="errorMessage" placeholder="Any error messages?">

  </form>
  
  <button id="summary">View Summary</button>
  
  <div class="output-container">
    <textarea id="output">
      <h2>Form Content</h2>    
    </textarea>
    
     <button id="copyForm">Copy Summary</button>
    
  </div><!-- #end output-container -->
  
  <p class="success"><strong>Form successfully copied</strong></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should keep return false; in function showInput() as form get submitted and there will be nothing to show

or make input type="button" instead of type="submit"